# what is wrong with matcher.find()?

Tags: java, regex

```
String s = "1.01";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[+-/\\*\\^\\%]").matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Input string is "1.01" and output is ".". I can't understand why matcher.find() returns true, there are no symbols like "+", "-", "*", "^", "%" in input string. Why did it happen?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `matcher.find()`.

Comment: No need to escape either of `*`, `^` or `%` in a character class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dash in any other position than the first or last inside a character class denotes a character range, just like `[a-z]` matches every lowercase letter from a to z, but `[-az]` only matches the dash, the a and the z.
If you look at http://www.asciitable.com/, you'll see that `[+-/]` will match any of `+,-./`

Also, you don't have to escape those symbols in a regex, especially not in a character class. As said before, your main problem is the position of the dash in the character class.

You can fix your regex from

```
"[+-/\\*\\^\\%]"
```

to

```
"[-+/\\*\\^\\%]"
  ^^
```

or without the unnecessary escaping:

```
"[-+/*^%]"
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you have to escape `-`.  `-` is used as a range symbol in character classes like in `[0-9]`.  The `-` needs to be escaped if you want to find examples of the dash.

If you reorder the symbols inside, you can get away with the entire pattern without any escapes.  `[-+*^%]` should work and is a bit easier to read.

Comment: The `+` inside a character class has nothing to do with repetition. But you're right regarding the dash.

Comment: @jlordo that makes sense, does it do anything different when it parses if the `+` is escaped inside a character class?

Comment: No, there is no difference. IMHO the escaping inside the character class makes the code less readable.